# Is there a way to write list field using the StreamWriter object?

Tags: parquet, streamwriter, apache-arrow

I want to store a list of strings in a column of a parquet table. I am able to do that using low level `arrow` APIs using the `arrow::ListBuilder` object and `parquet::arrow::WriteTable` call. I would like to do the same thing using the `StreamWriter` object too.

Apparently, `StreamWriter` object API does provide necessary methods for writing primitive types and strings but nothing for lists.

Is there a way to do that?